# Using json_encode to send html returns “null” string at the end

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I'm using this to load php functions and send them to javascript in a plugin, like:

```
function me_nav_query_submit() {

    $urlcall = nav_me_paises(); /* fetches a large html string */
    $response = json_encode($urlcall); /* encode to display using jQuery */

    //header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;

    exit;
}
```

I insert the html on the page, using

```
function(response) {
    jQuery('#navcontainer').html(response);
}
```

and everything works fine, except that i get a "null" string at the very end of the result.

`json_encode()` documentation talks about null strings on non-utf-8 chars, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I've also tried using `utf8_encode()` with no success. I've read a bunch of other questions here on SO, but most of them either talk about one given value returned as null or bad UTF-8 encoding and in my case everthing just works, and then append "null" to the end.

**note:** Defining that header() call is recommended in the WP Codex, but i commented it because it was giving a "headers already sent" error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** this is the function called:

```
function nav_me_paises() {
    ?>
   <ul class="navcategorias">
        <?php $tquery = $_POST['wasClicked']; ?>
        <?php $navligas = get_terms($tquery,'hide_empty=0') ?>
        <?php foreach ($navligas as $liga) : ?>
            <?php $link = get_term_link($liga); ?>
            <li class="liga"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" ><?php echo $liga->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: first of all we need to see your nav_me_paises()
and as for the header, it should be before any output

Comment: edited to include function :)

Comment: Please don't get this the wrong way, but reading your code was really a torture.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I really want to get better at it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nav_me_paises() is not returning anything. the html block is treated as output!

```
function nav_me_paises() {
 $output = '<ul class="navcategorias">';
 $tquery = $_POST['wasClicked'];
 $navligas = get_terms($tquery,'hide_empty=0')
 foreach ($navligas as $liga) {
   $link = get_term_link($liga);
   $output .= '<li class="liga"><a href="'.$link.'" >'.$liga->name.'</a></li>';
  }
  $output .='</ul>';
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: how embarrassing was that, huh? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`nav_me_paises()` doesn't return anything. Passing this "nothing" to `json_encode()` gives `"null"`. Convert the function so that it returns the HTML instead of outputting it

```
function foo()
{
};

var_dump(json_encode(foo()));
```

> ```
> string(4) "null"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if it's just plain HTML, why json it? Just send it to JS, it will be a string stored in a variable, and you handle it normally.

I presume all you wanna do is put that HTML inside some div, because you'd not parse it into a DOM and process its elements... because if u'd do that u'd not use HTML for it.